# Тест метода, который читает данные из файла (надо использовать mock)

Tags: java, юнит-тесты, testng, mock

Прохожу обучение по Java. У меня в проекте есть функция `readData(filePath)`, которая читает текст из файла и возвращает лист строк. Для её тестирования создаю в тесте файл с данными, на нём собственно и тестирую функцию. Но мне сказали, что надо использовать моки. Я погуглил, посмотрел примеры использования, но так и не понял, как применить к моему тесту. Подскажите, пожалуйста, как это сделать. Ниже мой тест и метод.

```
public class CubeDataReaderTest {

    File testFile;
    CubeDataReader cubeDataReader;

    @BeforeClass
    public void setUp() throws CustomException {
        testFile = new File("testData.txt");
        cubeDataReader = new CubeDataReader();

        try (FileWriter fileWriter = new FileWriter(testFile)) {
            fileWriter.write("1.0 2.0 3.0 4.0");
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            throw new CustomException("Data is not written.");
        }
    }

    @AfterClass
    public void tierDown() {
        testFile.delete();
    }

    @Test
    public void readDataPositiveTest() throws CustomException {
        List<String> expected = new ArrayList<>();
        expected.add("1.0 2.0 3.0 4.0");

        String filePath = testFile.getPath();
        List<String> actual = cubeDataReader.readData(filePath);

        Assert.assertEquals(expected, actual);
    }

    @Test(expectedExceptions = CustomException.class)
    public void readDataNegativeTest() throws CustomException {
        cubeDataReader.readData("notExistingFile.txt");
    }
}

public class CubeDataReader {
    static Logger logger = LogManager.getLogger();

    public List<String> readData(String filePath) throws CustomException {
        List<String> lines;
        try (FileReader fileReader = new FileReader(filePath);
             BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(fileReader)) {
            lines = bufferedReader.lines().collect(Collectors.toList());
            logger.info("File was read");

        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            logger.error("File not found.", e);
            throw new CustomException("File not found.", e);

        } catch (IOException e) {
            logger.error("Cannot read file.", e);
            throw new CustomException("Cannot read file.", e);
        }
        return lines;
    }
}
```

Comment: Посмотрите [File System Mocking with Jimfs](https://www.baeldung.com/jimfs-file-system-mocking#reading-file).

Comment: Нормальный подход Вы используете. Класс и метод плохо написаны. Моки туда просто не подсунуть.

Comment: Ок, спасибо. А как метод лучше сделать, подскажите плиз)